# Using Openssl to decrypt AES 128 bits CBC based64 text

Tags: encryption, cryptography, openssl

I am trying to use Openssl to decrypt the following AES 128 bits CBC based64 text (not padded) contained in the input.txt

```
bzxCHMWF+KVMumKb6rXTJQ0803fpYyxgdtZ8/nvc0Fc=
```

the first 16bytes are the IV. the encryption key is `h4ckth1sk3yp4d16`

I tried using the command:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d -base64  -K 6834636b746831736b33797034643136  -iv 627a7843484d57462b4b564d756d4b62 -in input.txt -out result.txt
```

in the input.txt, I remove the first 16 bytes of the encrypted text when running the above command.

but I kept getting the error:

```
bad decrypt 3073874120:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:532:
```

can anyone tell what's wrong here? thanks!

Comment: You need to Base64 decode the ciphertext, and *then* remove the IV. 16 is not divisible by 3 so it's not really possible to get/remove the IV without decoding first.

Comment: What is the character encoding of your `input.txt`? Could you show the value of `input.txt` in bytes (represented by hexadecimals)? Could you show us *how* you remove the first 16 bytes? And why?